# Vim-snipmate with vundle install not working

Tags: vim, autocomplete, development-environment, vim-plugin, snipmate

For some reason vim-snipmate doesn't want to complete snippets with tab. I have the following in my [.vimrc](https://gist.github.com/barcher/8049571), and used the [vundle install settings for vim-snipmate](https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate). Vundle installed the plugins inside '~/.vim/bundle/'. I've tried adding

```
set runtimepath^=~/.vim/bundle/vim-snipmate
```

and

```
set runtimepath^=~/.vim/bundle/vim-snipmate/after
```

to my .vimrc, but with no success. Any suggestions? What am I missing?

Comment: Those commands are useless. Does it work if you install snipmate normally? What snipmate? The original or the fork? If it's the fork, did you install the snippets bundle as well ?

Comment: So it would seem, but it was a suggested fix to a pathogen install. It's the fork at: https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate. They suggest using pathogen, vam, or vundle. I installed both the dependencies and the honza snippets.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether that fixes the issue, but the *after directory* should definitely be **appended** (`:set +=`), not prepended (`:set ^=`) to `'runtimepath'`:

```
:set runtimepath+=~/.vim/bundle/vim-snipmate/after
```

so that its value looks like

```
runtimepath=~/.vim/bundle/vim-snipmate,...,~/.vim/bundle/vim-snipmate/after
```